# Term Set Not in Managed Metadata Column

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, term-store, term-set, managed-metadata-column

I have created three Term Sets in SharePoint Online for a managed metadata column.  I cannot set a 'default value' for the column; and, the term sets are not available when I try to add them to that metadata column.  I'm the Term Store Administrator; and Contributor & Manager for each of the Term Sets.  I'm not sure if the error is in the Term Store or the Column.

Thank you for your time and assistance!

[image: Term Store Settings]

[image: Managed Metadata Column Info]

Comment: Do you have terms entered into your termset?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create a termset called companies, then add all companies as term in this term set. Like this:
[image]

Then in your managed metadata column, choose this companies termset.
[image]

Set default value:

[image]